# Is there an open source wiki that has both LDAP support and Confluence's ACL?

Tags: wiki

Open source wiki's are easy to find, but an open source wiki with both LDAP and Confluence's level of ACL is scarce. Specifically most wikis and CMSs have ACL for whole wiki pages, but not ACL for certain parts of a wiki page or individual files.

Does an open source wiki with these features exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently compared quite a few open source wikis but didn't see any with these granular ACL possibilities. A quick look at [WikiMatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org) showed me no matches, sorry (there are quite a few with ACL possibilities but like you wrote: only per page ACLs...).

Comment: yeah I've come away with the same conclusion myself after demo'ing and/or test deploying almost every open source wiki and CMS solution out there. 

It's surprising to know that after all these years, Confluence still has no open source equal.